# Remove unwanted characters from SQL retreival

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, data-retrieval

I'm using SQLite and Python3 and I'm trying to retrieve data from a database, however when I do so the data comes with unwanted characters. For example:

```
c.execute("""
SELECT Question from Questions
WHERE QuestionID='14-Ju-G5-Rad-Q7ai'
""")
```

Outputs the following: `'[(u'http://i.imgur.com/j306sbr.png',)]`

I just want the URL in the middle which is what is in the database.
How can I retrieve data without all the extra hoobly boobly?

Thanks

Comment: Is that link correct?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 yes, the link is correct but the '[(u' ',)] surrounding it isnt

Comment: Ok, I formatted your question so its more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not unwanted characters, what you get is a *list of rows* returned by the executed query. Each row is represented as a tuple.

If you need a single row, use [`.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone):

```
url = c.fetchone()[0]
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you, sorry for my poor wording of question everybody else, I'm a novice